# What conditions must satisfy the source term of an ODE given some boundary conditions?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Suppose you have this second order linear ordinary differential equation:

$$ \frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm d x}\left[\left(1-\frac{2}{x}\right)\frac{\mathrm du(x)}{\mathrm d x}\right]-(l+1)(l+2) \frac{u(x)}{x^2}=S(x)$$

where $u(x)$ is the unknown, $S(x)$ is a source term and $l$ is an integer $l\geq0$. (It is a particular case of the Jacobi equation)

This equation has two regular singular points in $x=0,2,\infty$. I am looking for a solution defined in $x\in [2,\infty)$ so that $u(x)$ is regular in $x=2$ and:

$$\lim_{x\to\infty}u(x)=0$$

$S(x)$ is finite in $x=2$ and goes to $0$ for $x\to\infty$.

To satisfy the second boundary condition I found (using Mathematica) that you need to have for $S(x)$ the asymptotic behaviour$^1$:

$$S(x)\sim \frac{1}{x^3},\qquad(\text{for }x\to\infty) $$

**Why is this the case?**

More in general, given a non-homogeneous ODE and Dirichlet-like boundary conditions (like in my example), **what should the behaviour of $S$ be on the boundary points so that the equation has a solution?**

---

**NOTES**

$1)$ Here's how I found this:

- Set $S(x) = \frac{1}{x}$ and $l$ to some integer number
- Solved the equation with Mathematica getting two integration constants $c_1$ and $c_2$
- Expanded in series the solution around $\infty$
- The solution is a polynomial in $x$ (+ $\mathcal O(x^{-1})$ terms) where the coefficient of the $x$ term and the constant term are independent of those constants. So no matter what you can't get a convergent solution for $r\to\infty$
- Repeat for $S(x) = \frac{1}{x^2}$ to get a solution that is constant at infinity and for $S(x) = \frac{1}{x^3}$ to get a solution that goes to $0$ as wanted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general question for arbitrary ODE is quite difficult. But in this specific case, there is some estimate of $S(x)$ that you can obtain.

Note that $\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty} u(x) = 0$, thus for large $x$, your equation is approximated by
$$x^2 \frac{d}{dx}\left[\left(1 - \frac 2x\right)\frac{du(x)}{dx}\right] = S(x)$$
Which is equivalent to
$$\frac{d}{dx}\left[\left(1 - \frac 2x\right)\frac{du(x)}{dx}\right] = \frac{S(x)}{x^2}$$
Since $\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty} u(x) = 0$, the limit of its derivative must behave similarly, so $\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty} u'(x) = 0$, by barbalat's lemma. Consequently, the LHS is $0$. Thus,
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty} \frac{S(x)}{x^2} = 0$$
This is true only if $S(x)$ has order smaller than $x^2$, e.g. $S(x) = x$, etc. I can't see precisely how Mathematica comes up with $S(x) \sim \frac{1}{x^3}$ for large $x$, but that does satisfy the above condition.

---

A very informal analysis does gives a better asymptotic estimation though. Since $\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty} u(x) = 0$, suppose $u(x)$ is of order $\frac{1}{x}$. This means for large $x$, $u'(x)$ is of order $\frac{1}{x^2}$. "Patching" things together you have something like this
$$x^2 \frac{d}{dx}\left[O\left(\frac{1}{x}\right) O\left(\frac{1}{x^2}\right)\right] - O\left(\frac{1}{x}\right) = S(x)$$
This is, loosely speaking, equivalent to
$$O\left(x^2\right) O\left(\frac{1}{x^4}\right) - O\left(\frac{1}{x}\right) = S(x)$$
Or
$$O\left(\frac{1}{x^2}\right) - O\left(\frac{1}{x}\right) = S(x)$$
Since $S(x)$ drives the equation, it has to goes to $0$ faster than any term on the left hand side, thus $S(x)$ is of order $\frac{1}{x^3}$ or lower. If it is of a lower order than $\frac{1}{x^3}$, then we can expect $u(x)$ to be of a lower order. But since $u(x) \sim \frac{1}{x}$ is perfectly fine assumption (without solving the equation and this is a very informal analysis), we conclude that
$$S(x) \sim \frac{1}{x^3}$$

---

**Edit:** with the new information, then I think my very informal analysis makes more sense (since you were simply trying out different solution for $S(x)$).

Comment: Yeah that's because I've mixed up two things... I have edited the post, now the equation is correct. Also added the explanation of what I did to find the $\frac{1}{x^3}$.

Comment: @FrodCube I edited it.

Comment: Are there any theorems that can give this result like given some properties of the singular points of the homogeneous equation or is this the only way to get it?

Comment: I believe there are theorems for well-known equations, but I don't know of one specifically.